# Include Loopback relation in POST response

Tags: loopback

I have a working chat-room loopback project, which also utilises Socket.IO.

Once I create a Message (POST to Loopback REST API), I need the response the include the 'creator' relation.

This works fine when using GET, but I cannot include the relation to the POST response.

I'm sure it's a simple remote hook, but I'm stuck...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
"relations": {
  "creator": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Person",
    "foreignKey": "",
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
  },
  "event": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Event",
    "foreignKey": "",
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Do you use a default POST method provided out of the box by loopback? You can try to override it to add some custom behavior. Have you already tried it?

Comment: Hi Peter. I was doing. I was looking for a way to do it, without having to create a custom method...

Comment: BTW, which version of loopback do you use? Is it 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Hi @James Clare, was the answer below useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options how you can do it with `Loopback 2.x` or `3.x` (not sure about the Loopback 4.x).

Let's assume we have the following `"Note"` model:

```
{
  "name": "Note",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "userId": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
      "user": {
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "model": "User",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
      }
  }
}
```

Now, to include `"user"` property (which is a `belongsTo` relation of `Note`) in the response when you `create` (`POST`) a Note you have two options.

**Option #1** (**Recommended**): Create a [custom remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html) and hide the default method in your model's script file. In this case your `note.js` file should look something like:

```js
module.exports = function (Note) {
    // Hide the default 'create' remote method
    Note.disableRemoteMethod('create', true);

    // Add a custom 'customCreate' remote method 
    Note.remoteMethod('customCreate', {
        description: 'Create a new instance of the model and persist it into the data source.',
        accessType: 'WRITE',
        accepts: [
            {
                arg: 'data',
                type: 'object',
                model: 'Note',
                allowArray: true,
                description: 'Model instance data',
                http: { source: 'body' },
            },
            { arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: 'optionsFromRequest' },
        ],
        returns: { arg: 'data', type: 'Note', root: true },
        http: { verb: 'post', path: '/' },
        isStatic: true,
    });

    Note.customCreate = function (data, options, cb) {
        Note.create(data, options, function(err, newObj) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
            }
            else {
                // here we try to load the user value
                newObj.user(function (err, user) { 
                    if (user) {
                        // if we found a user we add it to __data, so it appears in the output (a bit hacky way)
                        newObj.__data.user = user;
                    }

                    cb(err, newObj);
                });
            }
        });
    };
};
```

I would recommend using this option because you achieve what you need with minimal changes in the default logic of the loopback model, i.e. all the default methods like create, upsert, etc. continue to have default behavior.

**Option 2**: Use 'after save' [operation hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#after-save) (be careful with this approach as it changes the way how create, upsert, upsertWithWhere and other default methods work)

In this case your note.js file should look something like:

```js
module.exports = function (Note) {
    Note.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
        ctx.instance.user(function (err, user) {
            ctx.instance.__data.user = user;
            next();
        });
    });
};
```

The second option has less code, but as I mentioned before you should be very careful using it because it will change the behavior of default "create" method of the model. I.e. `'after save'` action will be executed each time you call Model.create, Model.upsert, etc. It will also slow down these operation as you add additional select query in the `'after save'` hook.